# Getting hardware accellerated 2d graphics with ATI card

Tags: debian, xorg, ati, amd-graphics

I run Debian 8.1 on an iMac G3 500 from 2001. The computer has an ATI Rage 128 PRO graphics card. In order for X to start it needs to know the horizontal sync frequencies and the vertical refresh rates supported by the CRT monitor:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Configured Video Device"
        Driver "r128"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "Configured Monitor"
        HorizSync 58-62
        VertRefresh 75-117
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Default Screen"
        Monitor "Configured Monitor"
        Device "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

With the above configuration file, X runs but the 2d performance is very slow; moving windows, for instance, is really lagging. According to the manual page for the r128 driver it *contains full support for hardware acceleration of drawing primitives*. My question is, basically, what settings do I need to add to get hardware acceleration? How can I tell whether hardware acceleration is in use or not?

Update 2015-07-15:

Here is the content of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`: http://textuploader.com/asl1o

Update 2015-07-25:

Here is the output of the command `dmesg`: http://textuploader.com/addvx

Update 2015-08-06:

The strange thing is that although `Xorg.0.log` says

```
[    84.669] (WW) R128(0): Direct rendering disabled
```

the `glxinfo` command thinks it's enabled:

```
$ glxinfo | head
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGI_make_current_read
```

Comment: Are you using open source or ATI's private drivers?

Comment: @YoMismo I use the free software driver `xserver-xorg-video-r128`.

Comment: Try with the private drivers, usually open source drivers don't have acceleration or full acceleration and lack from some benefits the private ones do. Debian has repositories for that, if my memmory serves me well they should be in the "non free" sources.

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't need to use an xorg.conf file, X will try the best counfiguration that fits your system drivers if that file is missing. When I asked about the video drivers I was talking about the system ones, not the xorg. Check the next link https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary.

Comment: @YoMismo there are no proprietary drivers for R128 on a G3...

Comment: You're right. Have you read https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo ? Do you have firmware-linux-nonfree libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-video-ati installed?

Comment: @YoMismo Without an `xorg.conf` I only get a black screen when I `startx`.

Comment: @YoMismo Yes, I have followed the guide wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo. As far as I understand the firmware only applies to Radeon cards.

Comment: I'm afraid the card is too old and no specific drivers for it are available any more. All I can read is that the performance of this card in linux without the drivers is slow even using only 2D rendering. :(

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom could you post the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` somewhere?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have added a link to the log file.

Comment: @YoMismo Sure, the card is old but the manual page of the driver I use (r128) states that it can do hardware accelerated rendering.

Comment: Try `Option "UseFBDev" "false"` at the end of your "Device" section

Comment: @YoMismo Disabling fbdev didn't make any difference.

Comment: The X log says `R128(0): Direct rendering disabled` which means that you don't have any acceleration; to figure out why DRI is disabled you'll need to look at the kernel logs. Could you post the contents of `/var/log/dmesg`?

Comment: @StephenKitt I have added the output of `dmesg`.

Comment: I think you need to check your kernel is configured and built with DRI support and rage128 driver, check your user is in group video and eventually manually add a xorg conf to enable DRI [What is DRI](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Xorg/Hardware_3D_acceleration_guide#What_is_DRI.3F)

Comment: @Alex How do I know if my kernel is configured and built with DRI? The guide you linked to is for Intel cards and Gentoo. Yes, I'm in the video group (default in Debian) and adding the DRI section did not make a difference.

Comment: @Alex Xorg.0.log says `Acceleration of RENDER operations will be enabled upon successful loading of DRI and EXA` and `EXA Acceleration enabled` and finally `Direct rendering disabled`. To me it is not clear if DRI is needed for 2D-acceleration.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom you should have a DRI device in `/dev`, I've it in `/dev/dri/card0` with major and minor `226, 0`, (if not you should check if your kernel come with a config file or if is in `/proc/config*`), you should also have a `rage128` into `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)`somewhere. I'll check about DRI for 2D

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom the driver should be called [r128](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/Kconfig) maybe you load it already `lsmod`? (I confirm the fw is named [r128_cce.bin](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/r128/r128_cce.c#L43)).

Comment: [EXA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXA) seems to be moving 2D primitives over 3D, I don't know the current status but.. worth a try?

Comment: @Alex I have no `dri` directory in `/dev` and no `/proc/config*` files. However, I do have the kernel module `/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-powerpc/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/r128/r128.ko`.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom first time I read your question I missed you're on a Debian, you should have `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` which is the `.config` of your running Linux kernel. Being a Debian probably DRI and DRM are already enabled

Comment: <stike>I did miss `glxinfo` output too (or is an update?) `direct rendering: Yes` DRI **is** working</stike>. Though you should check those dmesg messages: `aty128fb 0000:00:10.0: Invalid ROM contents` `vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device` (but aty128fb may be the driver for the graphic console (fbdev), not Xorg)

Comment: Sorry, DRI not really working: `server glx vendor string: SGI` mean `mesa`/software OpenGL is used.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but this moment, the r128 is no longer supported by ATi (it's supported in Debian Squeeze, which is still under maintenance but very outdated). However, you can enable some hardware acceleration by using the open source driver `xserver-xorg-video-r128` *plus* the non-free firmware `r100_cp.bin` contained in [firmware-linux-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-linux-nonfree) package.

Comment: `xserver-xorg-video-r128` is the driver I'm using and I have installed the package `firmware-linux-nonfree`. The firmware `r100_cp.bin` is only for ATI Radeon cards, maybe you mean  `r128_cce.bin` (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-linux-nonfree).

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I thought r128 cards are all the same (I have a Radeon 9200 and it uses the r100). But does the firmware work? Normally it would automatically get loaded in the kernel.

Comment: see [AtiHowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo) section *troubleshooting* make sure your firmware is loaded correctly.